# How to Auto-populate SQLCMD variable with Build/Assembly Version

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, sqlpackage

Using Visual Studio 2013 with TFS and SQL Server 2012 & 2014, and SQLPackage.exe with a Publish profile.

Does anyone know if/how to get the Build version or Assembly version into a SQLCMD variable?

i.e. I'm trying to obtain whatever system-level build versioning information TFS/Visual Studio has about an SQL project build and push this into a SQLCMD variable and then insert that into a table.

I know that I can explicitly define an SQLCMD variable and then manually set and increment the value of it, but I want whatever build version number has for the project.

I've been able to get the Assembly version info via MSBuild, as detailed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e0c93a55-d8bd-4a32-89d9-f46013fc1235/automatic-version-increment-on-datatier-applications?forum=ssdt

But that is outside of my `post-deploy.sql` script. I've tried simply referencing the `$(IntermediateTargetAssembly)` variable, but the project won't build and errors that this variable not been declared.

Comment: This article (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/10/19/maintaining-version-history-in-your-database-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx) is very close to what I'm looking to do, specifically the details around `/p:BuildVersion=&quot;$(BuildLabel)&quot;` but it applies to VS2010 and msbuild, rather than sqlpackage.

Comment: The way I did this was to put my properties into a publish profile, then update the publish profile at build time. As the publish profile is xml its just a case of replacing the inner text using an xpath query

Comment: @david-martin Currently I've got some a hard-coded `$BuildVersion` variable in the Publish profile and Post-Deploy script... are you saying that you are able to update the Publish profile xml with a dynamically generated value from a TFS/VS2013 property? or are you updating it with a value you are entering manually or lifting from a table? Thanks!

Comment: No sorry I don't do that, I have a property and update the publish profile prior to deployment via msbuild, think search and replace. Its not the best solution, but works for me, hence the comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a different deployment setup than you are currently using but I think you will find it may work out better overall.

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/

You could set the build version on your MSDeploy package using the MSBuild property you found via MSDeploy Parameterization to update a SQL script that would insert or update the source version in your database.